# Memory efficient check if the inputs have been repeated

Tags: python, memory

I get `N` int inputs and i want to check if they have been repeated. 
The simple way is just using the list and checking if new input is contained. 
However, for my, I know my inputs are `< N`, so I can just make a list

```
l = [0]*N
```

and then check if,

```
def getinputs(N):
    state = 1
    l = [0]*N
    for _ in range(N):
        i = int(input())
        if l[i] != 0:
           l[i] += 1
        else:
            state = 0
    return state
```

The problem here is that if N >> 1, then the size of list is very large and that causes problem. Is there more clever way to see if an input has been repeated?

Comment: You can use a dictionary with input values as keys and number of repetitions as values (only items which appear at least once are stored).

Comment: Do your `N` inputs follow a certain pattern? So that given say some inputs we can predict the others?

Comment: it sadly doesnot. it is pretty much random except it is int.

Comment: In that case, how about storing the inputs externally and then using [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-duplicates-in-on-time-and-constant-extra-space/) algorithm? (i.e. process each input by taking it inside the memory once) As long as you can store at least 2 inputs in-memory.

Comment: This would be O(n) time solution theoretically however, cost of IO operations might practically be significant.

Answer (score 3):

Use a set:

```
s = set()
s.add(3)
4 in s
# False
3 in s
# True
```

It's much better than a list for checking repeats since it's O(1) rather than O(n)

If you want to count the number of repeats, use a dictionary:

```
d = {}
d[1] = d.get(1, 0) + 1
```

Dictionaries also have an O(1) lookup

Comment: great answer, to expand on the time complexity for those who do not know, O(1) means that the time to perform the lookup operation is constant which means it does not change with respect to the size of n and is significantly faster than O(n) which grows linearly with the size of n.

Comment: I am not using `in` to search in the list, so the `set()` does not really solve my problem with memory use. I am not concerned about the speed but the memory. As N grows large size of set also increases and with due to `add` , the process also slows.

Comment: So you don't want to store the inputs to know if you have repeated one or not?

Comment: i am kind of storing input as shown in my code, i am trying to reduce the memory usages further if possible. So if there is a possibility without storing the input or even more optimised way of doing it, I would love to know. But making set or list of ints is definitely less optimal for large numbers.

Comment: A set() is most time-efficient, but in terms of memory usage, I see what you mean.  I mean one idea I have is to store the ranges of numbers you saw, so instead of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9 you can store 1~9, but then you run into stuff like 1~2, 4~5, ... Everything I look up always involves you getting an array prefilled with N elements, so it's no different from filling a set yourself from multiple input() calls

Comment: @hadik technically, you can store your inputs in a file that you read for every new input.  O(n) time to check duplicate, but extremely slow since you need to go to disk for the numbers.  I would put a cap on the file size so you don't fill your drive.